# Remove one of many markers on Google maps with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I currently add markers to the map using the code below. I'd like to be able to remove any one at any time by pushing a javascript command. Is this possible?

ex. place 5 markers.. removed the 3rd one while keeping the other 4.

```
$('#map').show();
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = document.getElementById("address").value +", " + document.getElementById("city").value;

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    locationsall[counter] = new Array();
    locationsall[counter][0] = address;
    locationsall[counter][1] = lat;
    locationsall[counter][2] = lng;
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locationsall.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locationsall[i][1], locationsall[i][2]),
    map: map,
    title: 'You are here!'
    });
}
counter++;
} else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
}
```

});
}

Edit 1:

```
        }).text("Remove").click(function() {
    var index2 = $tr2.index();
    $("#locationDeals input[type='hidden']").each(function() {
        this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function(str2, number2) {
          return "[" + (+number2 > index2 - 1 ? number2 - 1 : number2) + "]";
        });
    });
    //locationsall[locations.indexOf(location)].setMap(null);
    $tr2.remove();
    locations.splice(locations.indexOf(location), 1);
    return false;
        }).appendTo($tdRemoveRow2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of your `for loop` define an `Array` that will hold all added markers. E.g. `allMarkers = []`

Inside of your `for loop` after creating the marker, push it in said Array. E.g. `allMarkers.push(marker)`

When you want to remove the first marker: `allMarkers[0].setMap(null)`, or the third marker: `allMarkers[2].setMap(null)`

Comment: Please remember that the suggestion above only removes the marker from the map. It will not be garbage collected. For that to happen the entry in the array should be deleted.

Comment: You're absolutely right. But I chose not to confuse OP more than needed ;)

Comment: So I tried it but it didn't work with my situation. Do you have any advice on how to do it? (see edit1). Basically I have two texboxes that generate a table and map the address. Each tr has a remove button. I click the remove and it removes ti from the table. I'm trying to get it to remove it from the map as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. The Google Maps documentation covers this fully, including code examples, etc. Essentially markers are overlays rather than the map itself. You can put these overlays into an array and then use `setMap()` to null to hide.

Fully documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers).