# how to remove marker by id?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

If there are five markers (different id) placed at the location and if try to
remove single marker by id..

first user input id in textfield,when the delete link is pressed,marker remove suitable by id was inserted in textfield...
this my add markers code...

```
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
   makeRequest('get_locations.php', function(data) { //makeRequest is function to load data coordinat from db..... success!!

        var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);

     for (var i=0;i<data.lenght;i++){

       var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i]['latitude'], data[i]['longitude']);
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            id:i,
            position: myLatlng,
            title:"Dari db :" + data[i]['tempat']
        });

        marker.setMap(map);

     }

    });
}
```

How could i achieve this?
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove one of many markers on Google maps with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203323/remove-one-of-many-markers-on-google-maps-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You'd be best off assigning the markers to an array and then adding them as a group.

This way you can simply iterate through said array and delete the marker by Id, before adding the markers back to the map.

Hope this helps.